# Trying to use CASE statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table with the data as shown below,

```
create  table #UserRegion 
(
    UserName varchar(25),
    RegionName varchar(25),
    RegionID varchar(10),
    RegionStatus varchar(15),
    DefaultFlag char(1)
)

Insert into #UserRegion
values ('UserOne', 'Chicago', 'MW-1', 'Oniline', '1'),
       ('UserTwo', 'SanJose', 'W-6', 'Oniline', '0'),
       ('UserThree', NULL, NULL, 'Oniline', NULL),
       ('UserFour', NULL, NULL, 'Oniline', NULL),
       ('UserFive', 'Miami', 'E-4', 'Oniline', '0')
```

I want the result set as, if regionname/regionid null then it should the pick the regionname and  region id from available regionname and regionid where Defaultflag =1.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Aside: Using a `Char(1)` to store a `Bit` value provides a nice way to store data you don't want, e.g. `j`. If you don't expect to need additional values then you shouldn't allow them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would appear to have a very poor data structure.  Why are the defaults stored with the users?

In any case, this might do what you want:

```
select ur.*,
       coalesce(ur.regionname, urdefault.regionname) as regionname,
       coalesce(ur.regionid, urdefault.regionid) as regionid
from #UserRegion ur cross join
     (select ur.*
      from #UserRegion ur
      where DefaultFlag = '1'
     ) urdefault;
```

This assumes that only one row has the default flag set.

I should note that you can do this without a subquery:

```
select ur.*,
       coalesce(ur.regionname,
                max(case when DefaultFlag = '1' then regionname end) over ()
               ) as regionname,
       coalesce(ur.regionid,
                max(case when DefaultFlag = '1' then regionid end) over ()
               ) as regionid
from #UserRegion ur;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. only one row will has the default flag.